# VSCT Undefined 'Parent/@id' attribute

Tags: c#, vsix, vsct

This is my first attempt at creating a visual studio extension, so please bear with me if I'm a bit dense.  I'm stuck on getting the vsct file to compile (and hopefully do what I want it to do, but right now I'd settle for compile!)

The errors I'm getting are:

```
Undefined 'Parent/@id' attribute 'ToolsMenuGroup ' in a <Menu> element  MVCScaffolder
Undefined 'Parent/@id' attribute 'IDM_VS_MENU_TOOLS ' in a <Group> element  MVCScaffolder
```

My goal is to create a submenu off of the Tools menu as a place to collect our customizations.  To the user it should be:

```
Tools --> County of Lancaster --> Extension 1
                                  Extension 2, etc.
```

From what I understand from [How to: Create Menus, SubMenus, and Shortcut Menus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/Bb165707.aspx), I need to add a couple of groups in there to hold the menu items.  I believe the proper plan is:

```
IDM_VS_MENU_TOOLS (Tools) --> ToolsMenuGroup --> LancoMenu --> LancoMenuGroup --> Commands
```

And that's what I *thought* I had created.  Only the compiler seems to disagree.  Funny how the compiler always gets the last say.

Any help appreciated deeply!!  Here's what I have:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <CommandTable 
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005-10-18/CommandTable" 
      xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Extern href="stdidcmd.h"/>
    <Extern href="vsshlids.h"/>
    <Commands package="guidMVCScaffolderPackage">
      <Menus>
        <Menu guid="guidMVCScaffolderCmdSet" 
              id="LancoMenu" 
              priority="0x0100" 
              type="Menu">
          <Parent guid="guidMVCScaffolderCmdSet" 
                  id="ToolsMenuGroup "/>
          <Strings>
            <ButtonText>County of Lancaster</ButtonText>
            <CommandName>County of Lancaster</CommandName>
          </Strings>
        </Menu>
      </Menus>
      <Groups>
        <Group guid="guidMVCScaffolderCmdSet" id="ToolsMenuGroup" priority="0x0600">
          <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_MENU_TOOLS "/>
        </Group>
        <Group guid="guidMVCScaffolderCmdSet" id="LancoMenuGroup" priority="0x0600">
          <Parent guid="guidMVCScaffolderCmdSet" id="LancoMenu"/>
        </Group>
      </Groups>
      <Buttons>
        <Button guid="guidMVCScaffolderCmdSet" id="MVCScaffolderCommandId" 
                priority="0x0100" type="Button">
          <Parent guid="guidMVCScaffolderCmdSet" id="LancoMenuGroup" />
          <Strings>
            <ButtonText>MVC Domain Model Scaffolder</ButtonText>
          </Strings>
        </Button>
      </Buttons>
    </Commands>

    <Symbols>
      <GuidSymbol name="guidMVCScaffolderPackage" 
                  value="{44fd35ed-2596-4994-b72c-5b166acb077d}" />

      <GuidSymbol name="guidMVCScaffolderCmdSet" 
                  value="{4165f5d1-ccd0-4dee-97bb-f48a4f96c8ee}">
        <IDSymbol name="ToolsMenuGroup" value="0x1000"/>
        <IDSymbol name="LancoMenu" value ="0x0100"/>
        <IDSymbol name="LancoMenuGroup" value="0x0010" />
        <IDSymbol name="MVCScaffolderCommandId" value="0x0001" />
      </GuidSymbol>
    </Symbols>
  </CommandTable>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an extra space. It will be fine once you get rid of it.